# Mystery Ladies Bike

Tags: identify-this-bike

I haven't ridden a bike in more than 40 years, and just got a used one knowing very little other than it rides nice. Is that a K-Mart logo under the handlebars? I honestly don't know. If anyone can tell me a little bit about what kind it is, that would really be appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I note that the K in the head tube logo is similar to the K in a KHS logo, with the trimmed upper-left corner

[image]

So googling "khs bicycle logo" returned this as one of the matches:

[image]

So your bike is some model of KHS.

I've looked through back catalogues at https://issuu.com/khsbicycles and it appears as a woman's variant of the **GREEN 1** or **GREEN 3** which is listed in the 2013 to 2019 "Manhattan" catalogues.

The only sticking point in that is in no year was the bike available in Orange.  And the logo looks "factory" so unlikely to be repainted orange.  There are some years where RED was a released colour, but this bike does not look like faded red.

Also I have no idea what the "148" sticker on the chain case is referencing.

I think its probably a 2012 model or earlier.

[image: From catalog]

[image]

Link to 2019 version   https://khsbicycles.com/bikes/2019-khs-models/green-1-19/

Comment: WOW! That was a wealth of information I would never have put together, most likely. The two-tone orange color looks to be original. Thanks a million!

Comment: @robin218r if Criggie has the correct answer please select his answer as the right one